# Best way to parse DateTime to SQL server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I was wondering what is the best way to parse a DateTime object to your SQL server.

Where you are generating the SQL in code.

I have always used something like `DateTime.Now.TolongDateString()` and had good results, apart from today where i got a error, and it made me think.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string
```

So what is everyone thoughts and recomendations for a way that will work acrss all SQL server no matter what there setup..

Maybe something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`

Comment: I have now been using .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff") which seams to work just fine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there are only 2 safe formats

ISO and ISO8601

ISO = yymmdd

ISO8601 = yyyy-mm-dd Thh:mm:ss:mmm(no spaces) (notice the T)

See also here: [Setting a standard DateFormat for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se)

Comment: I am affraid that is not true in the database even the string '1997-12-09' can be treated either as 9th of December or 12th of September depending on the database settings. So you are never guaranteed how the string that you pass to the DB is going to be treated unless you specify the formatting.

Comment: Kristof, if you are going to use dashes in the format, then you need to use the T.  If you remove the dashes, then it will never be mis-interpretted.  Instead of '1997-12-09' use '19971209'.

Comment: Thanks Mastros - I was not aware of that, I guess you can learn something everyday :)

Comment: @SQLMenance - I will leave the first comment even though I was wrong when saying that your answer was not correct.

Comment: insert into testtable values ('0000-00-00T00:00:00') :)

Comment: Should ISO8601 be something like this? yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.FFF

Comment: Above has wrong clock (12-hour). Should be yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFF

Answer (score 10):

Why not parameterise the query and pass the DateTime value as a SQL DateTime input param?

e.g `INSERT INTO SomeTable (Blah, MyDateTime) VALUES (1, @MyDateTime)`

Then you can be really sure. Even if you're generating the SQL you should be able to handle this specifically?

Answer (score 10):

I found this specific format was needed:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Note casing and absence of any spaces.
This is the universal way according to [Robyn Page](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-datetime-workbench/#inputtingdates).

Answer (score 5):

You should really use parametrized queries for that and pass your **DateTime** object as a **SQL DateTime** parameter.

If you parse the **DateTime** to **String** you will have to deal with the localisation settings both on your application server as on the database server. That can lead to some nasty surprises like treating the Date as it was in US format on one side and e.g. UK on another. The string 9/12/2000 can be either September the 12th or the 9th of December. So keep the data in the **DateTime** object/type when exchanging between application and database.

The only time you would parse **DateTime** to **String** would be when displaying data (GUI). But then you should make sure to use the proper localization setting when parsing to display it in the format the user is expecting.

The same principle applies to other data types like **float** for example. The string representation of this varies depending on the locale and I suppose you do not parse **float** to **String** when passing it to the database so why do it with the **DateTime**?

Answer (score 3):

this one won't ever fail:
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff")

Answer (score 3):

Watch out if the date is DateTime.Min, as SQL Server uses 1700s for the start of time itself. I'd use an ISO datetime format : DateTime.ToString("s") but I haven't tried that on non-western installs.

e.g.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("c")
```

is

```
insert into testtable values ('2009-01-22T15:08:13')
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting using DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff") will match the MS SQL Server date/time format.  (I believe SQL Server is fairly "intelligent" about recognizing slightly different-looking formats, e.g. with slashes, but I've personally used that one successfully.)

EDIT:  As noted by commenter, this will probably be ruined in some locales.

Comment: this one will fail for ydm locale