# C# Convert DateTime To Sql Server 2005 Format

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datetime

#### How Can I Turn This DateTime value into something that Sql Server 2005 won't shout at me for.

2007-12-01T00:00:00+00:00

(All I care about is the date, NOT the time).

I get this error when I tried to pass this argument to my stored procedure as a DateTime variable (Both the C# object and the Sql Server object are DateTime variables and need to be)
:
"Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Comment: exact duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469417/best-way-to-parse-datetime-to-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to transform a date, that the sql server will accept is the following format: yyyymmdd, for example 20071201.