# Convert varchar 2007-12-19-11.57.17.366731 to datetime datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data as shown below

```
2007-12-19-11.57.17.366731
```

and the datatype is `varchar(26)`

I want to change only datatype to `datetime`.

I tried all syntax but no use and I am getting

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Here is the sample I am trying

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2007-12-19-11.57.17.366731', 120)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you'll need to add some string magic to transform your data into an accepeted format for `DATETIME`. And you also need to use less miliseconds (for `DATETIME` you  have 3 digits for it), in SQL Server 2008 you can use `DATETIME2` for this. Try the following:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(26)
SET @Value = '2007-12-19-11.57.17.366731'

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@Value,10) + ' ' + 
                         REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@Value,12,8),'.',':') + '.' +
                         SUBSTRING(@Value,21,3), 120) ValueAsDatetime,
        CONVERT(DATETIME2,LEFT(@Value,10) + ' ' + 
                         REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@Value,12,8),'.',':') + '.' +
                         RIGHT(@Value,6), 120) ValueAsDatetime2
```

Results:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║     ValueAsDatetime     ║      ValueAsDatetime2       ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ 2007-12-19 11:57:17.367 ║ 2007-12-19 11:57:17.3667310 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works but out of 100,000 I am getting only 75000 records. I hope few of the records are not in same format.After 75000 records the date may be in wierd format. so remaining records were not populating.I hope I think write case statement whatever the records are in different format make it as NULL and pass remaining 75000 records.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to offer an unacceptable `datetime` format.  This is the correct format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2007-12-19 11:57:17.366', 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this other question: [Best way to parse DateTime to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469417/best-way-to-parse-datetime-to-sql-server)

You have to pass a "safe" format to the DateTime function, which means you'll have to parse the string into its components, then pass it in the proper format to DateTime