# Convert date to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm somewhat new to T-SQL and despite reading a number of articles that indicate this should work, I'm having trouble converting October 1st of the current year to a datetime.

I've tried:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) + '1015' AS DATETIME)

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'Oct 15 ' + DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()),100)
```

And all kinds of variations.

Any ideas?  I need to set a datetime variable to whatever Oct 1st of the current year is.

Comment: You mention October 1st, but reference October 15th.  Which is it?

Comment: This is directly answered by the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Sorry about that - it's October 15th.  I also need one for December 7th of this year.  But I figured either example would be about the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse DateTime to SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469417/best-way-to-parse-datetime-to-sql-server)

Comment: Pheonixblade, I understand your comment, but my point is I've tried to follow it to no avail.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is very close. The problem is that the plus sign (+) for concatenation is actually giving you a numeric value, which you can't cast to a date.

To concatenate a year and '1015' and end up with a string, use the `CONCAT` function instead:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), '1015') AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Ed.  The other suggestions appeared to be going the opposite (date to string), and the concatenation stuff in SQL is a bit learning curve, very different than VB.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to is close, but DATEPART returns a number, so the "+" is doing addition, not concatenation.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '1015' AS DATETIME)
```

edit -- Ed beat me to it, and the Concat function is better too.

But if you really wanted to knock it out of the park, try this...

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 9, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, getdate()), 0)) As October1CurrentYear
```

No casting required!

Comment: +1 Your answer is also correct as `CONCAT` function is only available from `SQL Server 2012` onwards